# How to get the name of a file in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to store the name of a particular file in a property mediator in WSO2? I have looked in fileconnector but it does not have any thing that can get the name of file.

Comment: what file do you mean? could you elaborate your use case a little bit?

Comment: Like say a file names "Sample.xml" is there in "D:/folder1". How can I get the name "Sample" of file in say a property mediator?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to obtain a filename in your vfs proxy, you can use

```
<property expression="get-property('transport','FILE_NAME')" name="filename"/>
```

The variable "filename" will contain the name of currently processed file.